# Update screen when "all" asynctasks are done

Tags: android

I am using asynctask to do lengthy operations such as DB reads. I want to start a new activity and render its  contents when all the asynch tasks are done. What would be the best way to achieve this?

I know that onPostExecute is used to update screen. But I dont want to update screen unless all ther ayncTasks are done

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't overcomplicate it: just use a counter that gets incremented in every `onPostExecute`. If a task finds this counter to be maxed (equal to the number of tasks you spawned), it can run the update code.

Note that you don't need locking around this counter, since `onPostExecute` runs in the UI thread.

Comment: Ove this suggestion! clever one :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion, You can create an array of boolean that is sized to the number of Asynctask. Each Asynctask will have an ID which is index to the boolean array. In onPostExecute or other callback, you can check if all of the entry are true. Then you know it is all done. Another way is that, you assign unique id for each one of the Asynctask, and you also have the sum of those id, when one of them is done, you subtract its id from the sum, when it reaches zero, you also know they are all done. Not perfect, just some suggestion.

Comment: Thank you. I like the other solution but another user since it simplier. However. +1